# Can I exit an "as_completed" pool executor loop (cancelling all remaining tasks)?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

The idea is to run a set of tasks, process them as they finish, and as soon as one returns the desired result, cancel the remaining tasks. I don't mind waiting for tasks already started to finish, but starting new tasks should be forbidden.

I've tried calling `pool.shutdown(cancel_futures=True)`, but it doesn't seem to work here:

```py
import time
import multiprocessing
import concurrent.futures
import random

filelist = ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007', '008', '009', '010']
parallel = 2

def worker(name, lock, index):
    with lock:
        index.value += 1
        pc = index.value*10
        print(f'starting: {name} ({pc})')
    d = random.randrange(1, 5)
    time.sleep(d)
    return pc == 60

print('INIT')

with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
    lock = manager.Lock()
    index = manager.Value('b', 0)
    if parallel > 0:
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=parallel) as pool:
            tasks = [pool.submit(worker, filename, lock, index) for filename in filelist]
            for task in concurrent.futures.as_completed(tasks):
                rc = task.result()
                if rc:
                    print('Found!')
                    pool.shutdown(cancel_futures=True)
                    break
      else:
          for filename in filelist:
              rc = worker(filename, lock, index)
              if rc:
                  print('Found!')
                  break

print('END')
```

When running in serial mode (`parallel = 0`), I get the desired result:

```
INIT
starting: 001 (10)
starting: 002 (20)
starting: 003 (30)
starting: 004 (40)
starting: 005 (50)
starting: 006 (60)
Found!
END
```

But with parallel activated, it just continues till the end:

```
INIT
starting: 001 (10)
starting: 002 (20)
starting: 003 (30)
starting: 004 (40)
starting: 005 (50)
starting: 006 (60)
Found!
starting: 007 (70)
starting: 008 (80)
starting: 009 (90)
END
```

So, is there any way to exit the `as_completed` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it for example with `Pool` class from `multiprocessing` module
Example:

```py
from functools import partial
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


def child_process(x, stop_event):
    # stopping condition
    if x == 4:
        print('stop event is set')
        stop_event.set()
    # do something else
    time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("main process start")

    # Create exit event
    exit_event = mp.Manager().Event()
    # Create Pool
    pool = mp.Pool(2)
    print('pool started')
    start = time.perf_counter()
    pool.map_async(partial(child_process, stop_event=exit_event), range(20))
    while 1:
        if exit_event.is_set():
            # close pool
            pool.terminate()
            pool.join()
            break
    print(f'pool interrupted. Time took: {time.perf_counter() - start:.2f} s.')
    # do something
```

Out:

```
main process start
pool started
stop event is set
pool interrupted. Time took: 1.17 s.
```