# How to catch Exception in a for loop with ProcessPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have the following code:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def do_something(x):
    # This task can take some time
    # An error may occur

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for x in range(0,100):
        future = executor.submit(do_something, x)
```

I want the whole script to be aborted if an error occurs inside the `do_something` function.
Right now, the exception is just ignored. I want the error to be catched as early as possible. So if the error occurs for example within the first wave of the 10 workers, the script should stop. But the main for-loop should not explicitly wait for the finished processes.

I only found a method to check for errors either after the execution of the whole for loop is done, or through blocking wait inside the for loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception handling in concurrent.futures.Executor.map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071378/exception-handling-in-concurrent-futures-executor-map)

Comment: @enzo unfortunatly no. Through in the proposed solution the errors are "catched" in runtime, I can't find a way to use those to stop the whole script, as reraising them still only happens after all futures are done.

Comment: Please, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77483048/16591526